# Perl CGI: query parameters are munged following Perl upgrade

Tags: perl, cgi

We recently upgraded Perl from 5.8.4 to 5.16.1 (CGI version 3.59).  My web app has several pages which all pass data from one to the next via CGI forms.  When I insert a $query->Dump into each page, the first two pages are fine, but the third has completely munged data. The name/value pairs aren't what you'd expect, there are names that shouldn't exist, etc.  For example. page 2 contains expected name/value pairs:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

```
. selectedOrganism
    All
.  selectedExpters
    All
    LKRAMER
```

while page 3 has munged name/value pairs including:

```
. -----------------------------17694310364738783961604838496" 

   <with 12 null values>

. Content-Disposition: form-data

. All
     <3 null values>

. LKRAMER

     <null value>
```

This is running on our development box; our production box hasn't been upgraded yet, the code is the same and there is no problem.

Comment: Show us your HTML and your code.

Comment: Agree with @mob. We need something to go on here.

Comment: I'd be happy to oblige but I'd need to include literally thousands of lines, and believe me, you don't want to read them.  I guess what I'm looking for is whether a perl upgrade could cause problems with cgi?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  Instead of instantiating the query object as:

```
    my $query = new CGI;
```

The code had:

```
    my $query = CGI->new(\*STDIN);
```